# 16 bit assembly how system pause for seconds?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

how I can use int 8 in x86 [using masm in win xp] to system do no operation for seconds[pause]?
or any other int or code?

Comment: What OS?  Call your OS Sleep() API, pass DWORD 16000, probably.

Comment: how I can use this api in win xp?

Comment: @MartinJames: he won't be able to do that in 16bit asm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common ways in DOS programs:

- Count the changes of the 4-byte counter at address 40h:6ch. The counter is incremented every 55 milliseconds.
- Install your own interrupt handler for int 8 (IRQ0, timer interrupt) and count the interrupts. From your ISR you should call the original one, so the rest of the system works as intended.

The latter option may be more reliable under Windows.

Comment: I don't know how implement second way! also comparing many times have effect on CPU usage?

Comment: So, learn about interrupts. Obviously, every executed instruction uses CPU.

Comment: is normal 50% usage of CPU in first way implementation?

Comment: Only you can decide if it's normal, it depends on the rest of your program.